# How to review the changes before push into VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to know,is there any option in VSTS or how to review the changes before pushing the code into VSTS git. Please help here.

Answer (score 0):

Without sharing the code by pushing it to VSTS there is no way other people can look at it. VSTS however does have build in pull requests. This allows you to push your code as a separate branch and then have formal review process before accepting the merge of your changes.

You can find more info in the documentation: [Review code with pull requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/pull-requests)

Comment: @Marina Liu - MSFT,Thanks for your inputs here.But I need is there any option in VSTS before pushing the code by the developers into VSTS ?

Comment: @Marina Liu - MSFT, you mean to say that the who ever wants to review the changes before pushed into VSTS they need to run in their local source tree (client) software so that they will come to know the changes right ?

Comment: @Marina Liu - MSFT, The requirement is like before pushing into VSTS,who ever is trying to push the code into VSTS reviewer need to get warning/pop up window saying that changes approved or not approved.Then only push should be done in VSTS.if reviewer not approved the changes which are trying to push into VSTS then the developer should get an email alert saying that changes are not pushed.Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below commands to review the changes before pushing:

First, before reviewing the changes in your local repo, you should make sure all the commits from remote repo are pulled in you local repo. You can use the command `git pull` at first.

Then you can review the changes between your local branch (assume it’s `master` branch here) master and `origin/master`.

- **To review the commits which are not pushed to remote  branch**

  ```
  git log origin/master..master --oneline
  ```

  It will show the commits you made on local `master` branch but not push to remote repo yet.
- **To review the changed files between local `master` branch and remote master branch**

  ```
  git diff origin/master master
  ```

  It will list the difference for each changed file by comparing `master` with `origin/master`.

Comment: ,The requirement is like before pushing into VSTS,who ever is trying to push the code into VSTS reviewer need to get warning/pop up window saying that changes approved or not approved.Then only push should be done in VSTS.if reviewer not approved the changes which are trying to push into VSTS then the developer should get an email alert saying that changes are not pushed.Please help me on this.

Comment: No, since git is a kind of distribute VCS, it can not be gated before pushing in VSTS. The work around is adding branch policies, so developers can not push to the branch directly but need to merge into the branch via pull request.